# Unity - Cinemachine 2D - Reset lookahead

Tags: unity-game-engine

So when I respawn my player on a checkpoint, the camera goes back with the player just fine but it is applying the lookahead option and it makes a snappy camera change when you move the character.

Is there a way to reset the lookahead option when respawning via script?

Or is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable and enable it again:

```cpp
_virtualCamera.enabled = false;
_virtualCamera.Follow = target;
_virtualCamera.enabled = true;
```